# Android - dynamic size of the cardview

Tags: android, android-cardview

I want to show contact information inside a cardview and if needed, the cardview should be resized in order to contain all the information.

this is the layout part:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/cvClist"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#99CC00"
    card_view:cardElevation="10dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="52dp"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:id="@+id/ivContact"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:contentDescription="@null" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvContactName"
            android:text="dfd"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ivContact"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ivContact"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
            android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPhoneNumber"
            android:text="dfd"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ivContact"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ivContact"
            android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

but the `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` doesn't seem to have the desired effect.

[image]

Comment: Show your card item layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you align the name's field top border to the image's top border and the phone number's field bottom border to the image's bottom border. I guess you intended the phone number field to be below the name field: `android:layout_below = "@id/tvContactName"`

Comment: I did it for aligning purposes but you got that right